# Rewrite website content to load from subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am figuring out how to rewrite website content (images/js/css) for faster loading times.
This could also fix a "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" error for me.

Is it possible to rewrite
`content/dir/file.ext`
to
`http://content.domain.com/dir/file.ext`

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

However, if your intention is faster load times, you'd be better off changing the URLs in your code than to have Apache rewrite/redirect every request.

Given your current spec, that's the *right* way to do it.

Comment: Change the URLs for your resource files (images, css, js) in your code (HTML). So instead of linking to `content/dir/file.ext` and then redirecting, simply link straight to `http://content.domain.com/dir/file.ext`.

Comment: I am sorry, I meant the RewriteRule.